# LocalStorage wiped when upgrade app (previously using android cordova 7 and now android cordova 8)

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed a hybrid application (2 years now in the play store) that requires that one simple data persist in the localstorage between store updates. It did well (more than 12 version updates) until I switch to android cordova 8, the next update (in beta channel) erases all the contents of localstorage. This breaks fully the app for users not having backup.

Any clue about what is happening?

Comment: The websql database is wiped too..

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is not a cordova version problem... It is related to a plugin that encrypts the contents of the app, it seems to affect to the stored info. Removing this plugin everything works again.

Comment: which plugin was that?